# Deactivate email on 400 Bad Request with django 1.6

Tags: django, openshift

I installed django 1.6 on openshift and I'm receiving the following email every time somebody (or a bot) tries to access my website using the default openshift url.

> [Django] ERROR: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'example.rhcloud.com'.You may need to add u'example.rhcloud.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> No stack trace available
>
> Request repr() unavailable.

Is there a way to deactivate this notification other than adding 'example.rhcloud.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS? I still want to receive en error 400 when trying to access example.rhcloud.com, but not the email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppress admin email on django ALLOWED\_HOSTS exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384250/suppress-admin-email-on-django-allowed-hosts-exception)