# django 1.5 '[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /'

Tags: python, django

I've installed sentry for my django app and just switched from debug=True to False.
Ever since I've made this change I've been logging errors once every 10 minutes or so.

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/ubuntu/postalenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
response = middleware_method(request)

File "/home/ubuntu/postalenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 57, in process_request
host = request.get_host()

File "/home/ubuntu/postalenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 72, in get_host
"Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): %s" % host)

SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): localhost
```

In my allowed_hosts I have included my domain name. Any idea what this is caused by?

Comment: What do you have in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header

Comment: @BurhanKhalid ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xx.xx.xx.xx', 'www.domainname.com']. The first is my ip address.

Comment: What is the HTTPD and what's the configuration ?

Comment: The error clearly says you should include `localhost` in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov only if the OP wants the site to be accessible on localhost. If not, it could be users spoofing the header.

Comment: I've added localhost to my allowed hosts. No difference, I'm getting the same errors. Anyone know what actually causes the error?