# Django site doesn't work with DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, webfaction

I am using Django 1.5, and I am aware of the security issue [requiring the ALLOWED_HOSTS argument to include the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error#answer-15128309). The site is hosted on webfaction.

When I set my production site to `DEBUG = False`, I get 500 errors for every page. The error I get is:

> SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set
>   ALLOWED_HOSTS): www.mydomain.org

But in **settings.py**, I have the following:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mydomain.org']
```

This is making me crazy.  Any ideas?

**Edit:** This does not seem to be related to [header spoofing as in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header). My settings match the allowed host that appears in the error message.

**Update with solution:** I am embarrassed to say that I had a second `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ ]` declaration later in my **settings.py** file. This was overriding my previous declaration and causing the problem.

Comment: I made the same mistake - thanks for shortcutting the debug process for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you just have to put your domain formatted with a full domain name like :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mydomain.org']
```

This worked for me (no more 500 errors)

make sure you access your prod application via **www**.mydomain.org

Answer (score 0):

This Stackoverflow question will help you:

[Django's SuspiciousOperation Invalid HTTP_HOST header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header)

There's a ticket opened regarding this matter:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19866

Comment: This seems to be about cases in which the 'HTTP_HOST' header doesn't match the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting, but in my case it does.