# Django getting lots of SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header

Tags: python, django, apache, debian, linode

I'm using Django 1.5, Apache, mod_wsgi and python 2.7, debian hosted on linode.

Since I upgraded from django 1.3 to django 1.5, I started receive some error messages, for example: "ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /feed/". With this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 57, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 72, in get_host
    "Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): %s" % host)

SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): tadjenanet.montadamoslim.com
```

But, a few days ago, the volume of this errors increased greatly, and for a lot of url's that I don't even have in my website.

I saw the answers here([Django's SuspiciousOperation Invalid HTTP_HOST header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header)) and I understand why I'm getting this, but I need to know how to avoid this increasing my server security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you cannot avoid that an attacker send you that kind of requests. Most of this attacks came from automatic penetration test tools like [metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/) or [W3AF](http://w3af.org/). Fortunately, those attempts are not something to worry about in Django 1.5 or above. For avoiding the log flooding, you can configure your web server to filter HTTP_HOST headers that don't match with your website domain. Sorry, I cannot help you to do it with Apache, if using Nginx, this article can helps http://www.acloudtree.com/how-to-deny-hosts-using-nginx/

Cheers!