# django get the strange request while runserver

Tags: django

I am curious, I run the runserver with Django, the first request is what I am working on, but how about the others? I don't provide baidu server, why does someboy request it from my temporary server?

> [02/Feb/2018 12:20:05] "GET /stk/?format=json&_=1517542783567
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 2247 Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '1.164.39.192'. You may
>   need to add u'1.164.39.192' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. [02/Feb/2018 12:50:54]
>   "GET //wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 400 62538 Invalid HTTP_HOST header:
>   '1.164.39.192'. You may need to add u'1.164.39.192' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>   [02/Feb/2018 12:51:20] "GET /wp//wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 400 62571
>   Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.baidu.com'. You may need to add
>   u'www.baidu.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. [02/Feb/2018 14:15:00] "GET
>   http://www.baidu.com/cache/global/img/gs.gif HTTP/1.1" 400 62677

Comment: I think domain "www.baidu.com" is pointed to ip `127.0.0.1` check it in `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

if a request comes(like search engine crawlers etc.) with the HTTP host header which is not present in your ALLOWED_HOSTS setting Django create log like yours. 
Before they hit Django app you can kill these request. For solutions check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header)