# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'awssgp0-files.fds.api.xiaomi.com' request header attack

Tags: django, header, request, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, server-side-attacks

I am getting this request (more than 2000 per day) from different countries.

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: ‘awssgp0-files.fds.api.xiaomi.com’. You may need to add u'awssgp0-files.fds.api.xiaomi.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> Report at /yimotiondetection/2018/10/23/168333/DJVLPPMM81DCHLPN111A_1540282131_0.jpg Invalid HTTP_HOST header: ‘awssgp0-files.fds.api.xiaomi.com’. You may need to add u'awssgp0-files.fds.api.xiaomi.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> Request Method: PUT Request URL: http://awssgp0-files.fds.api.xiaomi.com/yimotiondetection/2018/10/23/168333/DJVLPPMM81DCHLPN111A_1540282131_0.jpg?GalaxyAccessKeyId=5661733440758&Expires=1540283933264&Signature=z9QvtfFxrlvtKiMiNiRGmMj2u/0= "

I am using elasticbeanstalk .

How to block these requests?

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP_HOST header attacks By adding allowed host in settings.py file will solve this issue.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your ip address here']
```

example

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['198.211.99.20', 'localhost']
```

Note: Don't make '*' to ALLOWED_HOSTS IF IT'S IN PRODUCTION.

For more reference Read Django website about ALLOWED_HOSTS https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: dear  jagamts1 please read the problem .. I have already done this . Now i am able to block request in app level .. need to block request as server side level ...

Comment: Yep you can do that by editing the nginx config and adding server_name.by default elasticbeanstalk using nginx as load balancer.
1.To change in nginx config file check following solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19703735/6345474
2.to check how to edit nginx in elasticbeanstalk 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html
https://medium.com/@marilu597/getting-to-know-and-love-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files-ebextensions-9a4502a26e3c
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html

Comment: by default i am using apache2.4         I added files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} PUT
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*(awssgp0-files\.fds\.api\.xiaomi\.com).* [NC]
            RewriteRule .* - [F,L]          .. but no help

Comment: don't change ssl_rewirte.conf file that has been used for http to https redirect even client didn't add https in his ip.check this link how edit apache.config to fix this error.http://blog.gabrielsaldana.org/avoid-djangos-invalid-http_host-error-message/

Comment: sorry actually it files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/block_urls.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*\.xiaomi\.* [NC]
            RewriteRule .* - [F,L]